# abstract api call and try catch block into one common method in JavaScript to make it more reusable

Tags: javascript, api, try-catch, abstract

```
export const getDatilsCall = async (testId) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axiosInstance.get(
      getUrl(DETAILS, { urlParams: { testId } })
    );
    return resp.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw handleExceptions(err);
  }
};

export const getDefaultCall = async (productId) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axiosInstance.get(
      getUrl(DEFAULT, { queryParams: { productId } })
    );
    return resp.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw handleExceptions(err);
  }
};
```

Let's say there is one api.js file which includes above methods, "getUrl" and "handleExceptions" have been abstracted already and I can use them directly. But it seems like for each api call, we need to duplicate try catch block includes "await axiosInstance.get" "return resp.data" and etc...

Do you guys think whether we need to abstract try catch block for above methods or the current way is good enough. Thanks.

**update my question based on the comments. What about I remove the try/catch and use try/catch on top level but how I can handle error part? Do I need to  throw handleExceptions(err) on top level?**

```
    export const getDefaultCall = async (productId) => {
      
        const resp = await axiosInstance.get(
          getUrl(DEFAULT, { queryParams: { productId } })
        );
        return resp.data;
     
    };
```

Comment: I don't understand completely your question, but I think the functions look good, the block try catch should work good, I believe that you have a try catch block in a top level for the "throw" in the catch

although if you have "try catch" in a top level, maybe you can skip "try catch" in funcitons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your post updated and I think that there is two alternatives

1. If you want manage particular error, about call axios or other code in your function, you can have "try catch" in your function `getDefaultCall`, for example:

```
 export const getDefaultCall = async (productId) => {
  try {

    const resp = await axiosInstance.get(
      getUrl(DEFAULT, { queryParams: { productId } })
    );

    // await anythings

    // await anythings

    return resp.data;
  } catch (err) {
    // manage special error, like custom message, or response structure json for other error manager
  }
};
```

but,

2. If you only want manage error, you can remove "try catch" in `getDefaultCall` and control your errors in top level

```
export const getDefaultCall = async (productId) => {
  const resp = await axiosInstance.get(
    getUrl(DEFAULT, { queryParams: { productId } })
  );
  return resp.data;
};

// use

something() {
  try {
    // if getDefault Call fail, jump auto to catch
    const data = await getDefaultCall();

  } catch (err) {
    
  }
}
```